# O que é parâmetro formal? E como faço?

Tags: c#

Estou com duvida se eu insiro os numeros ou usuário nesse tipo.

Comment: Há quem em vez de falar "parâmetro" e "argumento" diga "parâmetro formal" e "parâmetro atual/real" (ou outras variações)

Answer (score -3):

Parâmetros formais são as variaveis recebidas dentro de um método, função, onde são reutilizadas dentro dos mesmos.

EX:

```
public int Dividir(int valorA, int valorB)
{
    // Dentro desta função, "valorA" e "valorB" são parâmetros formais
    // Você pode realizar operações com eles e retornar um valor

    return valorA / valorB
}
```